# open camera in iPad phoneGap application

Tags: ios, ipad, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am using following function for capture image.

```
function openCamera() {
         navigator.camera.getPicture(
                                     function(uri) {
                                     var img = document.getElementById('camera_image');
                                     img.style.visibility = "visible";
                                     img.style.display = "block";
                                     img.src = uri;
                                     },
                                     function(e) {
                                     console.log("Error getting picture: " + e);
                                     },
                                     { quality: 50, destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI});
     };
```

And I am using following js of phonegap

```
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.2.0.js"></script>
```

I am using following image tag for captured image

```
<img style="width: 128px; height: 160px; visibility:hidden; display:none;" id="camera_image" src="" />
```

But its not open camera.Am not know what is the issue.?

Comment: areu testing on emulator or device?

Comment: I am testing it in real device.I know its not working in emulator.

Answer (score 0):

try adding the sourceType too..

```
 sourceType : navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA
```

Comment: where i need to add the line?Can you please write whole function for that?

Comment: include that in this  { quality: 50, destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI});

Comment: Its also not working.The same code working in android device but in IOS its not working.Is there any setting in plist file?